# What do the stats mean on replays and when spectating?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

When you're watching a replay or spectating on a game, there's a table of stats below the name of the player you're currently watching. What do the various stats mean?

[image]

Comment: Hint: When trying to censor information, you probably don't want to cover it transparently.

Comment: @Decency why are you so interested? It's not my profile anyway so I'm not too bothered ;)

Comment: @toryan why would you go through the trouble of "drawing out" a name if you can still read it regardless? Might as well have not went through the trouble to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- K = Kills

  - How many kills the player has made so far
- A = Assists

  - How many assists the player has made so far
- D = Deaths

  - How many times the player has died so far
- ADR = Average Damage per Round

  - In each round, the damage dealt is totalled up and divided by the amount of rounds so far to get this number
- 3K = 3 kills in one round

  - Self explanatory
- 4K = 4 kills in one round

  - Self explanatory
- 5K = 5 kills in one round (ace)

  - Self explanatory
- HS% = How many times player hits a headshot

  - For all your shots that land, the percentage of which you actually land a headshot
- OBJ = Bomb Plant/Hostage Rescue

  - How many times the Bomb Explodes, Planted, Hostage is Picked up, Rescued

Comment: @toryan Anything I might have missed out on?

Comment: What do 1st and 2nd mean? Also, are the stats for headshots (or anything else) a) specific to the gun they are carrying or across all guns, and b) for this round or the whole match?

Comment: Is the headshot% a measurement of headshots per total shots fired or per shots that hit an opponent? Does ADR and HS% count friendly fire?

Comment: @SimonL Friendly fire isn't tracked

Comment: Just to be accurate: Does OBJ mean bomb plants or bomb explosions?

Answer (score 2):

1st and 2nd refer to the match halves (15 rounds). So if you started as T, 1st would mean your stats on T side and 2nd would mean stats as CT.